# Vector perturbations in an expanding universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, space-expansion, perturbation-theory

Why vector perturbations in an expanding universe decay while the scalar and tensor perturbations don't?

Comment: It's because the vector mode is proportional to $1/a^2$, where $a$ is the scale factor. So as the universe expands, vector modes die out.

Comment: What about scalar and tensor perturbations? How would they evolve?

Comment: Tensor perturbations are just gravitational waves. Scalar, I forgot.